# Is there a way to round to 2 decimals in a template string?

Tags: javascript

How can I convert my getPriceWithOrWithoutDiscount to make sure it only shows 2 decimals.
The math has to be done with all decimals to make sure it's correct

```
var getTotalPriceAfterDiscount = 0;

products.forEach(function (product) {
  var occurence = cart.getOccurenceOfProduct(product.id);
  getTotalPriceAfterDiscount += occurence * cart.getPriceWithOrWithoutDiscount(product.id);
}

var output;
output += `
           <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Discount:</th>
                <td>\u20AC ${Math.round(getTotalPriceAfterDiscount)}</td>
           </tr>

          `;
```

Math.round doesn't work in template strings

Comment: It's `Math.round` (with lowercase "r"). In JS method names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the toFixed(n) method (n being the number of decimal places):

```
getTotalPriceAfterDiscount.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: "Math.round doesn't work in template strings" Why to expect `toFixed()` to work?

Comment: @Pavlo I suppose so, but this answer doesn't show how to use `toFixed` properly.